# Start mongodb with grails?

Tags: mongodb, grails, intellij-idea

I'm working on a grails app application that uses mongodb.

Before starting grails, I start mongod process. But to be honest, I'm a bit lazy, and I want to start mongo when grails is starting without going to terminal (I'm starting grails from intellij).

Is there a way to add it to grails startup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be enough to execute OS command in Bootstrap. For example call `Runtime.getRuntime().exec('/path/to/mongo/mongod')`